# Select column with values greater 0

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have an item database with 8 tables. There I wanted to write a stored procedure to select all values greater 0 for a specified item ID.
My problem now is the statement to return only the columns where the value of the specified item is greater 0.

Basically I write a simple select which returns the following data:

[Example 1 http://i.imagebanana.com/img/rhw2sm9u/1327501679.jpg](http://i.imagebanana.com/img/rhw2sm9u/1327501679.jpg)

When the Column "Cold" contains now a 0 value it returns the same structure like above but Cold is 0 instead of 120.

But if the value for Cold is 0 I don't want to get this column and discard it that I only get the remaining values:

[Example 2 http://i.imagebanana.com/img/dux1gyb8/1327502046.jpg](http://i.imagebanana.com/img/dux1gyb8/1327502046.jpg)

I'm using MSSQL Management Studio 2008 and the Database is 2008 R2.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my poor English.

Comment: How do you expect this to behave when multiple rows are returned, some with `Cold = 0` and some with `Cold > 0`? You can't return a jagged array with a select statement...

Comment: There won't be multiple rows. Every time one row only.

Comment: The images are missing - can you please edit your question and upload them using the editor's image uploader?

Comment: I will reupload them when I get home from work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A query is supposed to return a **fixed** set of columns. There's no syntax allowing you to return *some* columns conditionally only.

But you *can* invoke a query on a condition, with the help of the `IF` statement. So you could first check if the row you are about to retrieve contains a non-zero value in `Cold`. If so, you retrieve `Cold` with other columns, if not, you omit it:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE ItemID = @ItemID AND Cold <> 0)
  SELECT
    ItemID,
    ItemName,
    Cold
  FROM YourTable
  WHERE ItemID = @ItemID
ELSE
  SELECT
    ItemID,
    ItemName
  FROM YourTable
  WHERE ItemID = @ItemID
```

That is, the entire stored procedure definition would then look like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE YourStoredProcedure
  @ItemID int
AS
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE ItemID = @ItemID AND Cold <> 0)
    SELECT
      ItemID,
      ItemName,
      Cold
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE ItemID = @ItemID
  ELSE
    SELECT
      ItemID,
      ItemName
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE ItemID = @ItemID
END
```

Comment: This is the way to do it. The only difference is that I would put it in a procedure. Encapsulates it and makes it faster.

Comment: @Dave: Good point. I actually didn't even think about making it clear that this could/should be put into a stored procedure, probably because the OP had already declared their intention to write one, and I just focused on the essence of what the SP should do. Yet you are right to raise the point, for it never hurts to make oneself as clear as possible. So I've now added the full SP definition.

Answer (score 0):

you have to return a "value" for each row/column in a result set.  If you don't want to get `0` values, then you can turn them to NULL by using something like:

```
SELECT
    NULLIF(YourCol1,0) AS YourCol1, NULLIF(YourCol2,0) AS YourCol2, ....
    FROM ...
```

or

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN YourColumn1>0 THEN YourColumn1 ELSE 0 END AS YourColumn1,
    CASE WHEN YourColumn2>0 THEN YourColumn2 ELSE 0 END AS YourColumn2,
    ...
    FROM ...
```